# cursor adapter looses data when application minimized

Tags: android, android-widget, cursor

I am using a cursor adapter to retrieve the data from the database and binding it to the spinner control.
It's working fine but the problem occurs when user sending the application in the background after that all the spinner control looses the data.

Help me,
Waiting for your valuable answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ya it will happen, for that you have to save object Instance using below methods 0f Activity

```
 @Override
  protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState);
    // retrieve stored data
    savedState.get[...]
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // and place it
    outState.put[...]
  }
```

Comment: @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); fillSpinnerCity(); } I'm already using this.

Comment: this above are different method, add this to your file and search it how to use

Comment: I have a problem here...I'm using cityfunction(under onCreate) to fill city in the spinner from the database by using a cursor adapter and have no idea about calling that in onSaved or in onRestore.

Comment: onSaveInstanceState is called but onRestoreInstanceState is never called why...??